# Compilation error including clj-time in project

Tags: clojure, jodatime

I have included [clj-time "0.8.0"] in my project.clj. I then refer to clj-time in my namespace like so:

```
(ns school-finder.tasks
  (:require [clj-time.core :as t]))
```

However when I try and run the project I get the following compilation error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No single method: second of interface: clj_time.core.DateTimeProtocol found for function: second of protocol: DateTimeProtocol, compiling:(clj_time/coerce.clj:146:64)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known bug: https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/issues/124

If you just do a `lein clean` (possibly followed by a `lein deps`) that should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say where the problem is, so here's a working example:

project.clj:

```
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [clj-time "0.8.0"]]
  :source-paths ["dev"])
```

src/hello/core.clj:

```
(ns hello.core
  (:require [clj-time.core :as t]))

(println (t/now))
```

Comment: I have a minimum working project like you suggest and it works. However in my real project I get the problem as described. What I am unsure about is what might be the cause of the compilation problem and some idea of how to track the problem down.

Comment: lein deps :tree, and then look through the output to see if you are actually using the version of clj-time you specify. If you could include more of the code causing the error it would help